# JSON Validation Expecting '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

i have some data like this :

```
{"id":45332, "phone":401906}
{"id":735298, "phone":89607}
{"id":168511, "phone":63997}
{"id":153944, "phone":33930}
```

when i go to json linti com see the syntax error. how i can fix this error?

```
Error: Parse error
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

Comment: there should be comma's at the end of each closed bracket except the last one {"id":45332, "phone":401906},
{"id":735298, "phone":89607},
{"id":168511, "phone":63997},
{"id":153944, "phone":33930}

Comment: wrap in `[]` add `,` between each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON validator is trying to read the entire data file you have as though it's a single JSON object. However, what you have here is a series of JSON objects, separated by newlines. The error you're getting about the expected EOF ("end of file") is that the parser has thought it's done reading everything after seeing the first close brace, but then sees more data afterward and isn't sure what to do.

To fix this, either

- feed in each line of the file one at a time to the validator, so that you confirm that each item is indeed a single valid JSON object, or
- restructure your data so that it's a single, valid JSON object. One way to do that would be to convert it to an array by following @Lawrence Cherone's comment: put a `[` character at the front, a `]` character at the end, and intersperse `,` characters between the lines to form an array of four JSON objects.